# Can I use input type=time to specify a period

Tags: html, format, input

I have an HTML page with a time input that I use to set a period of time, say *one hour*, or *one hour and thirty minutes*

```
<input type="time" value="01:30">
```

This works okay, but depending on the locale, the display value may be `01:30 AM` rather than just `01:30`. This is good for specifying a certain moment of the day, but is meaningless for a period.

I could probably use a text input, or two numeric inputs for hour and minute, but the time input is very convenient here.

Is there a way to specify a display format, or get rid of the AM/PM indicator?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML input date and time will use the browsers local language/locale settings. You can easily test this behaviour by toggling which language you have on top of your language list in your browser. The AM/PM indicator is caused by the language set in browser. For instance in my norwegian language browser there is a 24 hour time picker.

You need to use more advanced date-pickers to get control of this or build something on your own using for instance multiple fields to represent year, month, day, hour, minutes etc.

More information found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date